# Is there a style proxy on UIComponent?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is there a style proxy on UIComponent? For example, instead of doing this:

```
myButton.setStyle("borderColor", 0xFF00FF);
```

I would like to do this:

```
myButton.styles.borderColor = 0xFF00FF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No in flex 4.6, there is no options to do this. The best way to set styles in `myButton.setStyle("borderColor", 0xFF00FF);`

You should go with this. Just set the properties name.